# In Pushing Ice how does the Lindblad artefact get there?

Tags: alastair-reynolds

The Lindblad cube just appears one day in orbit around Janus. How!?

I cannot recall even an attempt at a handwaving rationale for this irruption of narrativium.

Comment: I can't remember in that much detail, but wasn't it just that it suddenly started emitting something, so it was detected? Of course, there are much worse problems with Pushing Ice, not least that the whole concept is a blatant rip-off of *Spin*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman As _Pushing Ice_ was released two months after _Spin_, you'd have to give Alastair for efficient off-ripping ;)

Comment: I did have to look- **narrativium** is a Discworld pseudoword meaning: _the elemental substance of Story_.

Comment: @Solemnity More like seven months according to isfdb, but fair enough, I take it back. Let's call it synchronicity.

Comment: I was using **narrativium** to mean an arbitrary plot device. That may be a misuse of the term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cube arrived at the structure long before Janus and the Rockhopper did. It then simply sat there for a few ten/hundred million years, waiting for Bella's arrival and its discovery. To help illustrate this, look at the [timeline](http://approachingpavonis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/pushing-ice-timeline.html):

[image]

As you can see, the cubes were launched during the era of the Lindblad ring and had ample time for one of them to make its way to the structure. As Alastair Reynolds explains in a [comment](http://approachingpavonis.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/pushing-ice-timeline.html?showComment=1340737069206#c2079346359381916424) on his blog:

> Rockhopper was kept in a holding pattern (orbiting the galaxy, or something), so lots of time elapsed even without travelling megaparsecs in a straight line. The idea is that all the different species would have arrived at the Structure at around the same time, give or take a few 1000s of years. Enough cubes were thrown out such that one or more were bound to end up at the Structure.

To further elaborate, a quote from the book:

> We made vast numbers of cubes. Short of being dropped into a star, there isn’t much that can harm them. We were thinking long term, extreme deep time. [..] We scattered them to the four winds. Dispersed them throughout the galaxy via automated probes. Dropped them into orbit around a hundred million dead worlds. Cast them into intergalactic space, on trajectories that would eventually bring them into the gravitational influence of every major galaxy, satellite galaxy or globular cluster in the local group. We launched some of them far beyond the local group, towards the great galactic superclusters, halfway to the edge of the visible universe. They'll take a while to get there, of course. We even fired some of them into naked black holes, in the hope that their information would be encoded and released in the immeasurably distant future, when the black holes surrender their parcels of entropy back to the universe. We continued making them for four thousand years. Of course, we never really expected success - it was just a gesture, the decent thing to do.

In the first chapter, Chromis also explains: *"We'll make them by the billions and cast them to the four winds."*

Furthermore, the cubes had all the technology of 18'000 years of (accelerated) human development, which was capable of acts such as *"the frame-shifting of an entire world from one system to another"*. Each cube also had the full memories of Chromis and knew what to look for, so once a cube approached Janus it would have no problems identifying it. The frame-shifting and reeve technologies demonstrated towards the final chapters hint at the fact that the technology of the cube could be sufficient to bypass the Spican structure's barriers, or perhaps the cube found Janus before it reached the structure and simply followed it around during the time the Iron Sky was in place.

Comment: Thanks for the timeline. I'm still not clear how a cube found Janus, or why it stopped there when it did. Even once a cube has been curated into the structure, there are formidable barriers to free movement within it. The cube had to find Janus within a short time of our humans arriving.

Comment: I've expanded the answer with some quotes from the book to elaborate on your points.

Comment: Thanks. That starts to make some sense. But raises the question how come only one of the cubes made it there!?

Comment: If I made those cubes, I'd give them some algorithm to ensure there's no more than one in the same place, as that'd be redundant capacity better sent elsewhere. And I assume in 18'000 years we're even smarter than now ;)

Comment: @Flivver We don't know that for sure. They don't encounter any other cubes in their brief stay but the structure is huge, it's alluded to in the book that the crew may still encounter other cubes in the future.

Comment: @Ingmar if we are concerned about redundant capacity, the best outcome is to make then Von Neumann machines and then you dont have to worry about clumping or being spread too thinly...

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is that the cube was caught up in Janus' wake somewhere along the way. When it was discovered it was found orbiting Janus, not just floating around randomly in the structure.